Using clearAndSetSemantics doesn't allow Appium to identify views
We need to use clearAndSetSemantics to make certain views not focusable by accessibility services.
This is to give it a better feel, very similar example to https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/accessibility#custom-actions where we want the whole card to be focusable and not its actions.
However, the side effect is that Appium tests using UiAutomator2 cannot detect these views.
They have no semantic information, including content description, text and test tags/resource ids, even if they are set on these views as it's all being wiped by clearAndSetSemantics.
Is there a way we can keep the behaviour of clearAndSetSemantics to disallow services from focusing these views, as well as allow Appium to view these elements for testing?
